Raspberry Pi Zero 2W microphone and speaker setup not working
I am trying to set up a microphone and speaker for raspberry pi zero 2w. I am not a electronics student and am facing problems which this. my microphone is not getting detected and i can't hear any sound either.
There are the connections I am using:
PAM8302A Mono Amplifier

Vin: Connected to 5V on the Raspberry Pi (Pin 2).
GND: Connected
to GND on the Raspberry Pi (Pin 6).
A+: Connected to GPIO13 on the
Raspberry Pi (Pin 33) for audio input.
Out+ and Out-: Connected to
the positive and negative terminals of the mini metal speaker,
respectively.

MEMS Microphone Breakout

3V3: Connected to 3.3V on the Raspberry Pi (Pin 1).
GND: Connected to GND on the Raspberry Pi (Pin 9).
BCLK: Connected to GPIO18 on the Raspberry Pi (Pin 12).
LRCLK: Connected to GPIO19 on the Raspberry Pi (Pin 35).
DOUT: Connected to GPIO21 on the Raspberry Pi (Pin 40).

are these connections correct? do i need to do any other pin configurations?
I have checked all my connections and i added the following lines in my config.txt file.
    dtparam=i2s=on
    dtoverlay=i2s-mmap
    dtparam=audio=off
    dtoverlay=hifiberry-dac

